# Terminology for vertices in graph connecting vertices "in" and "outside of" a given component

Tags: graphs, terminology

Basically, I am looking for a (well-defined) term for some "*borderline*" vertexes interconnecting other vertices *in* and *outside of* a given connected component.

More specifically, given directed graph $G = (V_G, E_G)$ and (strongly) connected component $C = (V_C, E_C)$, how do people refer to such vertices $x$, where,

1. $x \in V_C$;
2. $\exists\ v \in V_G \setminus V_C$ such that $(x, v) \in E_G \setminus E_C$;

My friends have suggested names such as *gateway vertex* and *border vertex*. But I feel obliged to make sure we are not reinventing something well-known / well-defined.

It would be helpful if someone can help identify an equivalent (or likewise) definition of this concept in the literature. Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

Please note that -- unlike the well-defined concept of *cut vertex* -- the concept of *borderline vertex* (or whatever it should be called) is with respect to a *specific* given **component**, *not* the entire graph.

Comment: What is the purpose of using the vertex $u$ in your definition? I think you can define things better by dropping the $u$ and calling $C$ as a _maximal_ connected component. This would make sure that there is no vertex outside of $C$ which can be considered connected to $C$. (I assume that you mean _strongly_ connected when you say connected).

Comment: If $C=(V_C,E_C)$ is a connected component then there is no edge $yz$ with $y\in V_C$ and $z\in V_G\setminus V_C$. I'm afraid the set of vertices for which this property is held is the empty set.

Comment: @fidbc, which property are you referring to? No one said such edge $(y,z)$ should exist. I have improved the question for clarity.

Comment: @mayank, thanks for the comment. I meant that $C$ is a non-trivial component, i.e. it contains vertices other than $x$. This might be somewhat redundant. I have edited the question and dropped $u$ as you suggested.

Comment: @fidbc Note that this is a _directed_ graph, where strongly connected component means there is a path both from and to every vertex in the component from every other. Using your vertex names, there can be a directed edge from $y$ to $z$ as long as there is no directed path from $z$ back to $y$.

Comment: Since a component defines a cut, I'd say "cut-incident". But I don't know that this is standard terminology.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "standard" terminology. Gateway/border sounds good to me.

Comment: alternatively, you can say that the **out-neighbourhood** of $x$ is not entirely in the component (is not a subset of $V_C$)